# How to bucket fill area with a gradient in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, gradient, fill

I have a very simple problem. In the following image I want the pinnacles and other parts of my (admittedly very awesome) castle filled with some color and other shapes or outlines filled with other gradients.

For some very odd reason I cannot seem to tell the bucket fill tool to use a gradient? Or am I stupid? :)

[image]

Comment: For gradients It's the *Blend Tool*, not the *Bucket Fill Tool*.

Comment: Right, but that one will not allow for the Bucket Fill functionality, which is why I am asking explicitly for that :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this:

1. use the `Magic Wand` tool and click the empty area that you want filled
   with the gradient. There should be a dashed line inside the area.
2. Switching over to the [`Blend Tool`](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-gradients.html)
3. Pick your gradient
4. Apply gradient by clicking and dragging inside your selection, see image

[image: Step 4]

Update @Domi:
[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jle81ofRLok) video should give you an idea how I use layer masks. You can use this masking technique together with the Blend Tool to create a gradient that fills the pinnacle of your towers

Comment: The problem is that even though in this case the pinnacles have a rectangular shape, that might not always be the case. Take the windows for examples. They still have a relatively simple shape, but it's already a pain to accurately select each of them... and imagine now that you cannot copy and paste and you have more than three... It would be quite a pain to trace out all those shapes. You sometimes would have to trace pixel by pixel so you don't get pixel-sized holes along the edges... Seems a bit much, no?

Comment: Hmm..  I see what you mean. I believe that you are working in a single layer. Having each element on a single layer makes editing the image hard to do. 
For example you want the walls to have a castle kind of feel to them. You could use the pattern fill tool to add that feel to it. But it doesn't look good so `ctrl-z` to be able to try something else. If you saved and opened the file you are unable to use `ctrl-z` to change that. [video explaining layers](https://youtu.be/XhC0UNKD4CY)

Comment: I use layers a lot. Do you mean that I should add a layer that colors only roughly the area (using rectangle or some such selection) and then add another layer on top that makes use of bucket-fill outside of the area to cover unwanted gradient area?

Comment: You might want to learn about Layer Masks.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jle81ofRLok) should give you an idea how I use layer masks. You can use this masking technique together with the `Blend Tool` to create a gradient that fills the pinnacle of your towers.

Comment: @Damir Can you update your answer with the last part, so I can mark it as correct?